# how to get data from mat-option loop?

Tags: angular

I am using mat-select and option is fetching from database. In that table there is also column for images, and I want to change image outside mat-select when mat-option is change.

so how can I extract value outside loop of mat-option

I am add `selectionChange` in mat-option, but it is getting previous value, instead of current.

her are my code

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngIf="toggle[i]">
  <mat-label>Select Purpose</mat-label>
   <mat-select name="purposes" #purposeModel="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="purpose.id" [value]="purpose.id" (selectionChange)="onPurposeChange(purposeModel, purpose.id)">
    <mat-option>Select Purpose</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let p of purposeList" [value]="p.id" >
    {{p.title}} {{p.id}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and I want to display image which I will get in `p.iconsUrl`
this is code where I want to display image.

```
<div class="imageIcons" *ngIf="purpose.iconsUrl" >
            <img [src]="'assets/images/Purpose/' + purpose.iconsUrl" [alt]="purpose.title" *ngIf="!purposeChange" />
            <img [src]="'assets/images/Purpose/' + iconURL[purpose.id]" [alt]="purpose.title" *ngIf="purposeChange" />
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

bind `purpose` object to `mat-select` instead of `purpose.id`. try this;

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngIf="toggle[i]">
  <mat-label>Select Purpose</mat-label>
  <mat-select name="purposes" [(ngModel)]="purpose" [value]="purpose">
    <mat-option>Select Purpose</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let p of purposeList" [value]="p"> {{ p.title }} {{ p.id }} </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```